# Selection Sort C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Can you guys explain/simulate the selection sort algorithm, i tend to be lost on the exchanging part of the values. Thanks!

here is the code:

```
int[] ars = new int[4] { 5, 3, 10, 6 };
int min, tempo;
for (int i = 0; i < ars.Length -1; i++)
{
    min = i;
    for(int ii = i + 1; ii < ars.Length; ii++)
    if (ars[ii] < ars[min])
    {
         min = ii;
    }
    tempo = ars[min];
    ars[min] = ars[i];
    ars[i] = tempo;
}
```

Comment: Write each step down on paper and see what happens

Comment: Wikipedia page on selection sort has really good visualization of this algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort may be it could help you.

Comment: You may also take a look at this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg

Comment: @Aidin no, the `if` block is counted as one statement. So no extra brackets are needed.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Really? Did not know you could write it this way. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Aidin I'd rather give the `if` block an extra indent. So it would be more clear.

Comment: You find the smallest value in the array. Let's say you find it at index 17. You want to move that value to index 0. But since you cannot just throw away the value that was at index 0, you swap it with the value at index 17. Then repeat but swap the smallest value with index 1, then 2, etc

Comment: Also: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html

Answer (score 0):

It will iterate the list and **swaps** the current item with the lowest found on the rest of the list, but only when it is lower than the current item.

---

First you need to 'remember' the old value, before you copy the value.

```
// create copy of the previous value
tempo = ars[min];
// overwrite the old value.
ars[min] = ars[i];
// recall the previous value and assign it to the other in the array
ars[i] = tempo;
```